# How to delete an item opening a modal in php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

Hello I am really new in php and I am trying to create a modal which ask the user if the action is for sure. I think with the code it will be easy to understand because it is not really complicated and here it is:

```
<?php
$intros = "SELECT * FROM intro WHERE status !='2'";
$intros_run = mysqli_query($con, $intros);

if (mysqli_num_rows($intros_run) > 0) {
    foreach ($intros_run as $intro) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="code.php" method="POST">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?= $intro['id'] ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal <?= $intro['id'] ?>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" value="<?= $intro['id'] ?>" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                <?= $intro['id'] ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">No record found</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

So I want to ask the user if they want to delete the intro. I am opening the modal but  comes every time the same as the first id. I approve the click the delete button in the modal and as expected the first item in the database is being deleted.

Comment: Why is this indented so far?

Comment: All your modals will have the same ID, and all your buttons target the same ID. How is the browser supposed to tell them apart and open the right one, do you imagine??

Comment: yeah I got what you mean, how can I solve it?

Comment: Also, it barely makes sense to generate the modal multiple times. Make a single modal, and use JS to put the right data into it when one of the buttons to open it is clicked

Comment: @ADyson suggestion would be best, but you could place the ID in a hidden input field inside each form